# C# WinForms - custom font using does not work

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm loading the font from application's directory path. It works good on Win10 but it doesn't "see" the file on Win7.

```
private static PrivateFontCollection myFonts = new PrivateFontCollection();
    myFonts.AddFontFile(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\font.otf");
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: If the file can't be found, then the file might be in the wrong location. Are you sure that the file exists in the location given?

Comment: Surely you can be more specific than `does not work` and `doesn't "see"` - do you get an error message? If so, which one? If not, what happens?

Comment: @Venovani, yes I'm sure the file exists. It won't work on Win10 if it don't.  I'll try with TTF but exception message was "File not exists" :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from the MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.addfontfile.aspx

> FileNotFoundException: The specified font is not supported or the font
>   file cannot be found.

It also states

> Windows Forms applications support TrueType fonts and have limited
>   support for OpenType fonts.

So, try using a TTF file instead of an OTF file.

Comment: Works, great after conversion ;)